# Is the CallerMemberName attribute in 4.5 "able to be faked"?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.5

So .NET 4.5 introduces the `CallerMemberNameAttribute`, which seems like a godsend to anyone working with WPF and implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` - my question is this: Is the attribute intrinsically tied/supported by the <strike>4.5</strike> 5.0 compiler, or is it more of a syntactical sugar helper by the environment, much like one could fake out Visual Studio by declaring an `ExtensionAttribute` of your own, magically turning on LINQ syntax?

Edit: (sorry Jon!)
I guess I'm asking if one can "enable" the functionality of the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` in .NET 4.0 via redeclaration of the attribute in the proper namespace, much like one can "enable" LINQ query syntax in .NET 2.0 by proper declaration of the `ExtensionAttribute` class. My strong suspicion is no, naturally...

Put yet another way: I want to know if I can benefit from the functionality of `CallerMemberName` without upgrading to .NET 4.5/5

Hopefully that's more clear...

NinjaEdit #2: Sigh...version numbering conventions are confusing!

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear - there's no 4.5 compiler, because there's no C# 4.5. Are you asking whether you could use the C# 5 compiler against an earlier version of the framework, creating your own attributes that look the same as the ones in .NET 4.5? (Like the ExtensionAttribute *is* just tied into the C# 3+ compiler, and does *not* depend on the "environment".)

Comment: @JerKimball: there is no .NET 5, there is .NET 4.5 and C# 5.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, you can, exactly as you could use LINQ and .NET 2, as you said. I use the following in a .NET 4.0 project with the VS2012 compiler with success:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices {

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class CallerMemberNameAttribute : Attribute {
    }

}
```

Be *very* careful that everyone on the project is using VS2012, otherwise they'll get silent bugs because `CallerMemberNameAttribute` didn't do anything and `null` was passed as the parameter default.

**Edit 2013-06-28:** Consider installing the [Microsoft.Bcl](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/) NuGet package that provides `CallerMemberNameAttribute` (and some other classes from .NET 4.5) for .NET 4 and Silverlight rather than doing it manually.

Comment: Thanks! I was unsure if it was another "environment-enabled" attribute or something deeper - not having the assemblies installed (and not in a position presently to install them), my normal method of reflectoring was unavailable. :)

Comment: Installing Microsft.Bcl introduces dependency on kb2468871, so I'd avoid that if possible

Comment: @ghord Why?  It is a patch for .NET from 2011.  Everyone should have installed it already for security and stability issues.