# Empty CallerMemberName and such attributes

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core-3.0

It looks like `CallerMemberName`, `CallerFilePath`, `CallerLineNumber` attributes doesn't work in .Net Core 3.0 (values are empty).

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetObjects(
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        try
        {
        ...
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogException(e, memberName, sourceFilePath, sourceLineNumber);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

I tried to use the recipes [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840924) and [here](https://thomaslevesque.com/2012/06/13/using-c-5-caller-info-attributes-when-targeting-earlier-versions-of-the-net-framework/), but they don't work, too.

Is it a bug or a known feature? Or does I miss something important?

**EDIT**

My mistake was I added the attributes not to the function I needed to add into. I changed my code to

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetObjects()
{
    try
    {
    ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogException(e);
        throw e;
    }
}

private void LogException(Exception e, 
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        _logger.LogError(_event, e, "Exception in {memberName}, {sourceFilePath}, {sourceLineNumber} ", memberName, sourceFilePath, sourceLineNumber);
    }
```

and now it works as expected.

Comment: This is a C#/VB.NET feature, where the compiler sees these parameters when compiling the _call site_, and embeds the values so the caller provides them when calling this method. But given the `[HttpGet]` attribute, it's an API method. What would you expect to be provided for those parameters? How _do_ you call this method? I hope you don't expect to see some values like `myjQueryCallback`, `site.js`, `42`?

Comment: Does *your* code call `GetObjects` at all? If not, why did you add those features? API methods are called by the ASP.NET Core infrastructure. If you want to troubleshoot it, check the call stack during execution, or the HttpContext, or check the configured middleware

Comment: @CodeCaster, @PanagiotisKanavos, thank you. Now I realize my mistake. I should add attributes not to `GetObjects` function, but to `LogException` one. And it works as expected.