# CallerMemberName Attribute not working with EventAggregator

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, eventaggregator

I am working in Prism where `CallerMember` attribute is not working well with my code. I have a `Close` method and want to know from where the `Close` method get calls. Normally the memberName parameter marked using `CallerMember` attribute should receive calling method name. But the Subscribing and unsubscribing code shows, this eventAggregator has some invalid arguments. Any help would greatly appreciated.

```
private void Close(bool isOKCommand,[CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{
        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<ShowWarningMessageEvent>().Unsubscribe(this.Close);
        if (isOKCommand)
        {
            //Doing some operations;
        }
}
```

Comment: Is Unsubscribe(this.Close) not working or memberName variable is always empty, or what?

Comment: which .net framework you use

Comment: @devhedgehog The newly added "memberName" parameter would not allow to compile the code. It shows "Invalid arguments". I have not any issue with subscribing and using CallerMember attribute.

Comment: It is 4.5 guys else he wouldnt be able to use CallerMemberName at all and you must be having method overload issues or you must be calling Close somehow wrong. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: this is not an issue related to `CallerMemberName`, your `Unsubscribe` method for eventaggregator is used in a wrong way, please refer Prism documentation on how to unsubscribe...

Comment: @devhedgehog One can use `CallerMemberName` in VS2012 with .NET 4.0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381917/is-the-callermembername-attribute-in-4-5-able-to-be-faked

Comment: Ok well yea, VS2012 compiler and .NET 4.0... My fault, still the error is invalid arguments and not couldnt find attribute blah blah... The OP must be using the method in a wrong way. The definition is fine. He is also on .NET 4.5 as he recently added.

Comment: Regarding VS1 comment, is **this.Close** your subscriber´s EventHandler? You would need to set the subscriber's handler as argument for the Unsubscribe method, or a subscription token as an alternative which you would get when subscribing to the Event. For more information, you could check the following **Prism** section at **MSDN**: "[Subscribing to Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec14)".

Comment: @VS1 The Unsubscribe and Subscribe is working fine in other areas, I have only issues in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

There could be an issue in the way you have called and used `Unsubscribe` method of `EventAggregator` which is the *reason* you are getting `Invalid Arguments` exception.

> Unsubscribing to a Prism Event requires either a **subscription token**
>   returned by the Subscribe method or a **callback delegate** you passed to
>   the Subscribe method. Please refer [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921131.aspx) for more information

```
SubscriptionToken subscriptionToken = this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<ShowWarningMessageEvent>().Subscribe(<YourSubscribeMethod>);
this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<ShowWarningMessageEvent>().Unsubscribe(subscriptionToken);
```

Comment: Subscription token is not necessary to Unsubscribe an EventAggregator