# How to enforce parameter with [CallerLineNumber] to be read only?

Tags: c#, .net

`[CallerLineNumber]` is a great language feature. But I'm using it to [automatically order class properties as their declaration order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17998371/695964). However when the user calls the function or constructor with this parameter, the user is able to feed a value to it, which completely beats the purpose of auto-generation. Currently, I have to name this parameter something like `_doNotSet`, as a hint to the caller to not set this parameter.

How can I force it to be read only, or even better, hide it from the function signature?

The other thought I had was to mark the parameter as `[Obsolete]` so by using it the compiler will warn. Unfortunately, `ObsoleteAttribute` is not targeted for parameter, so I can't mark a parameter as so.

Comment: This could be an issue if it was actually related to a "user", but in reality this minute issue is only related to potential coders and nothing a doc comment won't handle.

Comment: This piggy-backs onto the compiler support for optional arguments, a hard requirement to let the compiler generate the value.  There is no possible syntax to make you happy, no lack of /// options to educate the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised that the compiler doesn't override the value passed in by the calling function. Anyway, accepting that unfortunate behavior I don't think there is going to be anything you can do to *guarantee* no one will break that.

As far as I am aware, the closest you could come is what you have done. Name it something like `_doNotSet` but I would suggest something like `_settingThisBreaksTheTool`. Depending on the audience of the code this may be enough to satisfy your needs.

**Edit:** This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/849zff9h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) shows how to determine if a value was supplied or not, unfortunately none of the tactics supplied there are going to work for you. Basically they suggest using a known unlikely value (impossible in your case since you won't know the line number or you wouldn't care). Or *don't* use default values and overload the function. But the `[CallerLineNumber]` attribute *needs* the parameter to be optional to work. Bugger.

**Come on Microsoft... Why**

This goes into how .Net implements default values for optional parameters. When you specify that a parameter is optional on a function, and call that function with no value something quite special happens during compilation. The code which does *not* have a value for that parameter is replaced with code which *does have a value, the default value.*

I read a few blog posts on this awhile ago, [this](http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/04/16/exploring-internal-implementation-c-4-0-default-and-optional-arguments/) was the simplest to understand the basics.

I may be making a few jumps here but my guess is that the `[CallerLineNumber]` attribute signals the compiler to use a different value, namely the line number. **But** the compiler won't even go through the process to inject values since there was a value in the first place.

Probably Microsoft would like the `[CallerLineNumber]` to override the value passed into the function, but the side affect of piggybacking default values probably caused them to not be able to support that. I will be interesting to see if the [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) project brings some enhancements with that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface like `ICallerLineNumberPlaceholder`.

```
public Task<TResult> ExecuteWithArgs<TResult, TParam>(Func<IDBLambdaEngine, TResult> queryExpression, TParam param, ICallerLineNumberPlaceholder placeholder = default, [CallerLineNumber] int callerLineNumber = 0) where TResult : new()
{
    return InternalExecute<TResult, TParam>(callerLineNumber, param);
}
```