# Get attributes in order of declaration using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Similar to [Get properties in order of declaration using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062235/get-properties-in-order-of-declaration-using-reflection) I want to get attributes in the order of their declaration. Obviously, I'm referring to attributes having `AllowMultiple` set to `true` for their `AttributeUsage`.

I wonder if [MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Attribute.GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs2dx40d(v=vs.110).aspx) guarantee any ordering (I haven't found anything in the MSDN).

Comment: I'm not sure anywhere defines order for these; you might also want to look at [GetCustomAttributesData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributesdata(v=vs.110).aspx), but that also isn't explicitly in declaration order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# language specification says in [17.2 Attribute specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664616(v=vs.71).aspx):

> The order in which attributes are specified in such a list, and the order in which sections attached to the same program entity are arranged, is not significant.
>
> For instance, the attribute specifications `[A][B]`, `[B][A]`, `[A, B]`, and `[B, A]` are equivalent.

So the compiler can re-order them as it wants, and the methods for retrieving attributes can't  guarantee to return them in any order.

You can of course use the [workaround proposed in the question you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17998371/266143), using `[CallerLineNumber]`.

Comment: So, I guess I would have to include an Order property in my custom attribute. Thx.