# Prevent sorting on Implement Abstract Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Given the following `abstract` class:

```
public abstract class AbstractTest
{
    protected abstract void B();
    protected abstract void Aa();
    protected abstract void Ab();
    protected abstract void C();
}
```

In Visual Studio Code, if I select "Implement Abstract Class":

[image: Implement Abstract Class example]

The methods are automatically generated by ascending, alphabetic order:

[image: Implement Abstract Class result]

---

Does there exist a setting in VS Code that allows me to retain the order of the methods, in the order which I had originally defined them in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio and VS Code use the Roslyn language services to enable these kind of code fixes.

In order to figure out which members are missing from the implementation, Roslyn [uses simple reflection](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/8919c7a2062196a9bfda5a4161157e7343a6d111/src/Workspaces/Core/Portable/Shared/Extensions/INamedTypeSymbolExtensions.cs#L414) on the base type.

Unfortunately, with reflection, there is [no guaranteed member order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062235/get-properties-in-order-of-declaration-using-reflection) at all. Compiled IL also does not have any member order, so it’s technically just not possible to get the member definition order from a compiled type. The only way would be to actually look at the source file; but that’s just not how Roslyn works.