# How to sort Type properties by a custom attribute

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have created a custom attribute that implements several properties that will accept values for their usage as shown below.

```
public class CustomAttribute : OrderAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Ignore { get; set; }

    public override int Order { get; set; } = -1;
}

public abstract OrderAttribute : Attribute
{
    public virtual int Order { get; set; }
}
```

After that, I have created class models to use the `CustomAttribute`.

```
public abstract class Person
{
    [Custom(Name = "Frist Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Custom(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Custom(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    [Custom(Name = "Address", Order = 2)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Custom(Name = "Grade", Order = 5)]
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

Since I'm using this with the C# Reflection, I have to use the `typeof` and get the class properties. This is when I have to sort the order of the properties based on their defined order using the `OrderBy`.

```
typeof(Student).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .OrderBy(KeySelector)
    .ToList();
```

Using this method in the `OrderBy`.

```
private static int KeySelector(PropertyInfo prop)
{
    var attr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttribute>();
    return attr?.Order ?? -1;
}
```

However, what it does is this:

1. FirstName
2. LastName
3. Email
4. Address
5. Grade

What I want is for any property that has the `[Custom(Name = "Test")]` and not implement the Order property is to be retained on its order or that has default order value of `-1`. So the order should be something like:

1. FirstName
2. Address
3. LastName
4. Email
5. Grade

Comment: Linq is not really that suitable for shuffling elements around in a sequence/list/array following some arbitray shuffling rule/logic. Not impossible, but often impractical. Better get all PropertyInfo's in an array/list first, and then shuffle them around there (you will have to code the shuffling logic) according to the information provided by the attribute(s). (Btw, just to confirm: The _Order_ property in your attribute is really a _Position_ property, right?)

Comment: @elgonzo yes it is.

Comment: What order do you expect the properties to be in if they don't contain an `Order` value? `GetProperties` itself doesn't guarantee an order.

Comment: @DavidG leave them be or retain to their position, it should position the properties with defined order to their respective position. so if the `Address` has an order of 2 it should be place after the `FirstName`.

Comment: In reality, the order will most likely be the base class properties first which means address in p1 and grade in p2. This means firstname is P3, so leaving things in position makes address come first.

Comment: @DavidG yes I notice that during debugging or outputting the properties order. Can it be first to sort the properties to let the base class properties to place at the top of the derived class then recalculate the position of those properties with a defined order to be placed to their respective position?

Comment: you have `[Custom(Name = "Address", Order = 5)]public int Grade { get; set; }` Should be Grade instead of Address in the attribute?

Comment: @Vlad I just corrected that

Comment: It can be done, but this is all very hacky. Are you really sure you need this? The ordering shouldn't be important.

Comment: @DavidG yes I need this it will be used in an excel as columns that is why the property ordering is important

Comment: Then put an order on all your columns...

Comment: @DavidG it can only be done by sorting the properties beacause I'm using generics to generate a report based on the class property name and value

Comment: Then let your report define the order of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, it's a bit long winded because as mentioned in the comments the order of the result of `GetProperties` is not guaranteed. With .NET 4.5+ there is a way around that as described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9062846/3911233).

So, the first part is to make sure we can get the properties of the class and its base class(es) in a predicatable order regardless of our custom order. To do that we recurse from the base class upwards and gather the properties that are declared in each, sorting the results by the order in which the property appears in the class.

```
public static IEnumerable<PropertyMetaData> GetPropertiesOrdered(Type someType, int inheritanceLevel = 1)
{
    List<PropertyMetaData> seenProperties = new List<PropertyMetaData>();
    if (someType.BaseType != (typeof(object)))
        seenProperties.AddRange(GetPropertiesOrdered(someType.BaseType, inheritanceLevel + 1));

    var properties = someType
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
        .Select(a => new PropertyMetaData(a, inheritanceLevel))
        .Where(a => a.AttributeData != null);

    properties = properties
        .OrderBy(a => a.AttributeData.ClassOrder)
        .Select((a, ordinal) =>
        {
            a.OrderWithinClass = ordinal + 1;
            return a;
        });                        

    return seenProperties
        .Union(properties)
        .OrderByDescending(a => a.InheritanceLevel)
        .ThenBy(a => a.OrderWithinClass)
        .Select((a, ordinal) =>
        {
            a.OrderOverall = ordinal + 1;
            return a;
        });
}
```

To support that, the attribute changes slightly as below to use the compiler line number attribute as in the answered linked:

```
public class CustomAttribute : OrderAttribute
{
    public CustomAttribute([CallerLineNumber]int order = 0) : base(order)
    {

    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Ignore { get; set; }
    public override int Order { get; set; } = -1;
}

public abstract class OrderAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly int _classOrder;
    public OrderAttribute([CallerLineNumber]int order = 0)
    {
        _classOrder = order;
    }

    public int ClassOrder { get { return _classOrder;  } }
    public virtual int Order { get; set; }
}
```

So, now we've got the existing properties in a predictable, numbered order, starting with the base class `Person` properties then followed by the top level `Student` class properties. The output of the `GetPropertiesOrdered` method is a container class with information about the order of the properties encountered, the custom attribute associated with each, and code to handle the custom sort - which is, if an order is defined then prefer it to the order of the properties seen in the type.

```
public class PropertyMetaData : IComparable<PropertyMetaData>
{
    public PropertyMetaData(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, int inheritanceLevel)
    {
        InheritanceLevel = inheritanceLevel;
        PropertyInfo = propertyInfo;
        AttributeData = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttribute>();
    }

    public int InheritanceLevel { get; set; }
    public int OrderWithinClass { get; set; }
    public int OrderOverall { get; set; }

    public CustomAttribute AttributeData { get; set; }            
    public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; set; }

    public int GetOrder()
    {
        return HasCustomOrder() ? AttributeData.Order : this.OrderOverall;
    }

    public bool HasCustomOrder()
    {
        return AttributeData.Order != -1;
    }

    public int CompareTo(PropertyMetaData other)
    {
        var myOrder = GetOrder();
        var otherOrder = other.GetOrder();
        int compare = myOrder.CompareTo(otherOrder);
        if (compare != 0 || other == this) return compare;
        if (HasCustomOrder() && other.HasCustomOrder()) return 0;
        if (HasCustomOrder() && !other.HasCustomOrder()) return -1;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Putting it altogether it can be called like this:

```
var propertiesSorted =
    GetPropertiesOrdered(typeof(Student))
    .OrderBy(a => a);
```

Which gives us back the fields in the required order for your example:
[https://dotnetfiddle.net/dd5hVN](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dd5hVN/)

Comment: If you have a virtual property in the Person and override this in Student class it will get both property, see the example -> https://dotnetfiddle.net/dcP4ny so any properties that are overridden in the derived class should not include those properties in the base class.