# Convert anonymous type to List<object>

Tags: c#, reflection, anonymous-types

I have a set of anonymous object dumped from a database which contains many fields (up to 50).

Example :

```
var anonymousData = new
        {
            Z = "2",
            B = "4",
            C = "3",
            D = 5
        };
```

I'd like to have the following output with such data

```
List<object> allObjects ... with { "2", "4", "3", 5 };
```

What is the correct way to reflect it ?

EDIT : I'd like to keep the initial order

Comment: What order do you want the fields in? Alphabetical? Don't care?

Comment: I'd like to have it as it appears.

Comment: No can do. The order in which properties are returned from reflection is undefined.

Comment: @Rango : Because some fields are integer and guid.

Comment: Did you try anything so far? We won´t give you the entire solution here, you have to think yourself.

Comment: Can you get the order of properties from anywhere else? If it's CSV, can you define the order yourself?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're declaring an anonymous object when you really want a list? The answer to your question is that if you need the values in the declaration order, it can't be done. Reflection is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netframework-4.7.2) to not guarantee the order of the properties so you'll have to accept that the order is not going to necessarily match the declaration, or you'll have to declare your values in a different manner.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen : The particular reason is that I'm too lazy to create a class with 50+ fields. But looks like I have to anyway. The time I spent posting a replying here is longer than creating this class but I'm just someone who's alway try to look for a better solution.

Comment: What I meant was, why can't you simply do `List<object> data = new List<object> { "2", "4", "3", 5 }` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via reflection you can get all values:

```
var anonymousData = new
        {
            Z = "2",
            B = "4",
            C = "3",
            D = 5
        };

Type t = anonymousData.GetType();
Property[] p = t.GetProperties();
List<object> xy = p.Select(x => x.GetValue(anonymousData)).ToList();
```

You added, that you want to keep the ordering of your properties in the result-list. This is not possible - Think about an object of type Car:

```
new MyCar { Id = 3, Color= "red"};
```

this is not different to a car like

```
new MyCar { Color= "red", Id = 3};
```

when the properties are switched. Imho, an anoymous type is nothing different. So when exporting it to CSV the sorting of your properties shouldn't make any difference - for this case you possibly should take a look at `Dictionary` otherwise.

Comment: This doesn't produce the order that the asker requested.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9062846/1086121 - relying on the order is a bad idea

Comment: Sorry @canton7 but what about posting an answer that does what the OP want? Imho, this is the closest possibility to do what OP wants. Otherwise the structure that OP uses (anonymous type) is wrong. He maybe should have used a SortedDictionary or an array or something else ..

Comment: There is no solution to the question the OP is asking: there's nothing I can post that will answer the question. Personally I think an answer like this, which might or might not solve the OP's problem, and might randomly break at any point in the future, needs to come with a warning which says as much. Otherwise the OP might believe that this is a true solution, and is setting themselves up for a nasty surprise in the future.

Comment: @canton7 : No, contrary of what you think I acknowledge all your comment. I perfectly understand that it's not a reliable solution and I will not use it. I will create my own list manually.

Comment: @PabloHoney glad to hear. It's not just you though: someone in the future might come across this answer and not realise that it depends on implementation-defined behaviour, which is why I think that fact should be highlighted.