# Serialize each property to the byte array

Tags: c#

I'm currently facing a problem, where I'd like to merge unaligned bytes of each property of a class and therefore basically get a serialized byte array only representation (depth-first serialization). By unaligned, I mean the case, where not a full byte/int/short is needed, but only just a few bits of each property.

So, consider this entity class:

```
public class Data
{
    public byte Type { get; set; }
    [BitfieldLength(4)] public byte NumberOfOptions1 { get; set; } // nibble
    [BitfieldLength(4)] public byte NumberOfOptions2 { get; set; } // nibble
    public uint MajorVersion { get; set; }
    public byte MinorVersion { get; set; }
    [BitfieldLength(24)] public uint TTL { get; set; } // 3 bytes
    public ushort EventsCounter {get; set;}
    
    // 12 bytes total
}
```

The **BitfieldLength** is a custom attribute class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class BitfieldLengthAttribute : Attribute
{
    public BitfieldLengthAttribute(uint length)
    {
        this.Length = length;
    }

    public uint Length { get; }
}
```

Here is the extension code to extract the bytes from each property:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static byte[] GetBytesFromProperty(this PropertyInfo field, Data data)
    {
        Type propertyType = field.PropertyType;
        
        if (propertyType == typeof(ushort))
        {
            return BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort) field.GetValue(data));
        }
        else if (propertyType == typeof(uint))
        {
            return BitConverter.GetBytes((uint) field.GetValue(data));
        }
        else if (propertyType == typeof(byte))
        {
            return new[] {(byte) field.GetValue(data)};
        } 
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"Unknown type: {propertyType}");
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the last part:

```
var data = new Data();
data.Type = 1;
data.NumberOfOptions1 = 2;
data.NumberOfOptions2 = 3;
data.MajorVersion = 5;
data.MinorVersion = 1;
data.TTL = 20;
data.EventsCounter = 120;

foreach (var prop in typeof(Data).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
{
    byte[] bytes = prop.GetBytesFromProperty(data);
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} => Value: {1} => Type: {2} => Bytes: {3}", prop.Name,
        prop.GetValue(data), prop.PropertyType,
        BitConverter.ToString(bytes));
}
```

If I'd concatenate each byte array from each property, the output would be **14 bytes** instead of the expected **12 bytes**...

And here is, where I'm stuck. How to twiddle this bits and bytes to the correct output?

EDIT:

Someone in the comments noted that the order of the properties is unpredictable. That's true, however, please take a look to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17998371/1362848.

Comment: Can you post why 12 bytes are expected? And how you came up with that expectation?

Comment: Your code never takes in account of `BitFieldlength`. The smallest part you want to get is 4 bits, so less than a byte, so I would write a method `string GetBitsAsTextFromProperty(this PropertyInfo field, Data data)` that returns strings like e. g. "1011" for NumberOfOptions1, and later convert the whole string to a byte array.

Comment: Of course my code didn't take the BitFieldLength into account, since I don't know how to proceed here.

Comment: Important: the reflection APIs explicitly do not make any promises re order, so: without some order metadata that you add, this can never be deterministic. There is no such thing as field declaration order: it does not exist as a concept that you can query reliably. The bit twiddling should just be some masking and shifting: not trivial, but entirely doable. Side note: BitConverter is almost never a good solution to most problems (in particular, it is CPU-endian, and allocation-heavy)

Comment: You need to use `GetCustomAttribute` to get the value of `BitFieldLength`. You need something like `BitArray` to append the bits to, although that particular class is not very well written. You need to be able to append arbitrary bit lengths from `int`s directly to it, without looping. I would implement `GetBytesFromProperty` as just a `(long value, int bitMask)` tuple, which covers most basic types.

Comment: Definitely, you should use `StructLayout` with fields to ensure predictability.