# How to make custom order for PropertyInfo[] C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can I order PropertyInfos?
I have a class:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public File File { get; set; }
}
```

And I get the properties using `typeof(Test).GetProperties();`

How can I order them by type?
Example:

```
typeof(Test).GetProperties().OrderBy(new List<Type>()
{
    typeof(File),
    typeof(string),
    typeof(int),
    typeof(bool)
});
```

So result will be :

> File, Text, Number, IsActive

If there was a different list of hints, the result should also be changed.

Can it be done?

Comment: See this answear about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9064293/468973

Comment: Your `OrderBy` parameter isn't a lambda. Assuming `OrderBy(p =>`, use `List.IndexOf` or `Array.IndexOf`: `new[] { typeof(File), typeof(string), ... }.IndexOf(p.PropertyType)`.