# Is there a simple way to generically parse data from strings for child class properties of differing types in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

I have a base class

```
abstract public class containerClass {
    protected containerClass () {
        // do stuff
    }

    virtual protected void parseData() {
        // do the stuff I'm mentioning later
    }
}
```

and child classes

```
public class childClassOne : containerClass {
    public childClassOne () : base () {
        var1S = "99";
        var2S = "88.3";
        var3S = "2015-04-22T15:55:25.2625065-07:00";
    }
    public int var1 {get; protected set;}
    public double var2 {get; protected set;}
    public DateTime var3 {get; protected set;}

    public string var1S {get; protected set;}
    public string var2S {get; protected set;}
    public string var3S {get; protected set;}
}
```

and

```
public class childClassTwo : containerClass {
    public childClassTwo () : base () {
        var1S = "99.22";
        var2S = "88.3";
        var3S = "43.44";
    }
    public double var1 {get; protected set;}
    public double var2 {get; protected set;}
    public double var3 {get; protected set;}

    public string var1S {get; protected set;}
    public string var2S {get; protected set;}
    public string var3S {get; protected set;}
}
```

What I want to do is define parseData in the parent class to iterate through the properties when it's called by a child class and parse the strings for relevant data.

Order needs to be preserved.  And the strings might be external data, not properties or fields of these classes.

My current thoughts in pseudo-code are something like:

```
for (property prop in thisClass)
{
    typeof(prop) temp;
    if (typeof(prop).tryParse(var1S, temp))
        prop = temp;
}
```

All of the class I'm looking at have a tryParse method with two input variables.  Can what I'm trying to do work?  If so, how can I iterate over the properties in an unambiguous order?

Comment: You want your parent class to be aware of your derived types properties?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ - what is the motivation behind wanting to create this pattern?

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "And the strings might be external data, not properties or fields of these classes." I'm not sure what the implications are here.

Comment: "Order needs to be preserved." Would sorting the reflection-provided list of properties alphabetically by property name be a way of doing that?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I lost my connection right after posting.  The strings probably won't be properties.  The important thing is that I need to read the strings in the same order as the properties, so that I know which class'  try parse to use.

Comment: @jdphenix my motivation.  I have six child classes and each one has different properties, but they each need very similar parseData functions to deal with those properties.  It would be nice to be able to write a single function instead of six.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple? No.** Possible? Yes.

> What I want to do is define parseData in the parent class to iterate through the properties when it's called by a child class and parse the strings for relevant data.

The following does the first part of your question. [Here is a fiddle to demonstrate](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MnicRW).

```
virtual protected void parseData()
{
    // iterate through the properties when it's called by a child class
    foreach(var p in this.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        // and parse the strings for relevant data
        var propName = p.Name;
        var propValue = p.GetValue(this);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", propName, propValue));
    }
}
```

> Order needs to be preserved.

This is where it's no longer simple. [MSDN says that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3yx7k228%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), "The order of the returned collection is not guaranteed to be identical between calls."

This question [`Type.GetProperties` property order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872254/type-getproperties-property-order) has an answer recommends a custom attribute to preserve the order. That could look like this:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ProperyOrderAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public int Order { get; private set; }

    public ProperyOrderAttribute(int order)
    {
        this.Order = order;
    }
}
```

You would use it like this on your properties.

```
[ProperyOrderAttribute(0)]
public int var1 { get; protected set; }
```

And you would [compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it like this:

```
protected Comparison<PropertyInfo> comparer = (x,y) => {
    var type = typeof(ProperyOrderAttribute);
    var xAttr = x.GetCustomAttributes(type, false);
    var yAttr = y.GetCustomAttributes(type, false);
    var xOrder = xAttr.Count() > 0 ? 
        (xAttr[0] as ProperyOrderAttribute).Order : 
        Int64.MaxValue;
    var yOrder = yAttr.Count() > 0 ? 
        (yAttr[0] as ProperyOrderAttribute).Order : 
        Int64.MaxValue;
    return xOrder.CompareTo(yOrder);
};
```

This is how the final `parseData()` method, with order preserved, would work:

```
virtual protected void parseData()
{
    var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();

    // maintain the order
    Array.Sort(properties, comparer);

    // iterate through the properties when it's called by a child class
    foreach (var p in properties)
    {
        // and parse the strings for relevant data
        var propName = p.Name;
        var propValue = p.GetValue(this);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", propName, propValue));
    }
}
```

Again, [this fiddle demonstrates the complete solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MnicRW).