# Loops in an array for iterate data fields

Tags: c#, asp.net

what should i do with this task, Im so stuck with this.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        string FileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        if (FileExtension == ".csv" || FileExtension == ".xls" || FileExtension == ".xlsx")
        {

            string filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadExcels"), new Guid() + ".xlsx");
            try
            {
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(filename);
                string excelConnectionString = string.Empty;
                excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";

                if (FileExtension == ".xls")
                {
                    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
                    filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                else if (FileExtension == ".xlsx")
                {
                    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                    filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }

                string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

                string[] Fields;
                Lines = Lines.Skip(1).ToArray();

                Dictionary<string, Int32> emlist = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                List<TaskExport> emList = new List<TaskExport>();
                foreach (var line in Lines)
                {
                    Fields = line.Split(new char[] { ';' });

                            emList.Add(

                                new TaskExport
                                {
                                    Plant = Fields[0],
                                    Prod__Number = Fields[1],
                                    Order_Number = Fields[2],
                                    Vehicle_Number = Fields[3],
                                    Delivery_Number = Fields[4],
                                    Vehicle_Type = Fields[5],
                                    Engine_Type = Fields[6],
                                    Plant_Dispatch_Date = Fields[7],
                                    Interior = Fields[8],
                                    Paint = Fields[9],
                                    Model = Fields[10],
                                    Country_Name = Fields[11],
                                    Engine_Number = Fields[12],
                                    Sample_Digit = Fields[13],
                                    Number_Of_Code = Fields[14],
                                    Codes = Fields[15],
                                    Number_Of_FZEG = Fields[215],
                                    Country_Code = Fields[216]
                                });





                    using (ExportExcelEntities table = new ExportExcelEntities())
                    {
                        foreach (var db in emList)
                        {
                            var dt = table.TaskExports.Where(s => s.ID.Equals(db.ID)).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (dt != null)
                            {
                                dt.Plant = db.Plant;
                                dt.Prod__Number = db.Prod__Number;
                                dt.Order_Number = db.Prod__Number;
                                dt.Vehicle_Number = db.Vehicle_Number;
                                dt.Delivery_Number = db.Delivery_Number;
                                dt.Vehicle_Type = db.Vehicle_Type;
                                dt.Engine_Type = db.Engine_Type;
                                dt.Plant_Dispatch_Date = db.Plant_Dispatch_Date;
                                dt.Interior = db.Interior;
                                dt.Paint = db.Paint;
                                dt.Model = db.Model;
                                dt.Country_Name = db.Country_Name;
                                dt.Engine_Number = db.Engine_Number;
                                dt.Sample_Digit = db.Sample_Digit;
                                dt.Number_Of_Code = db.Number_Of_Code;
                                dt.Codes = db.Codes;
                                dt.Number_Of_FZEG = db.Number_Of_FZEG;
                                dt.Country_Code = db.Country_Code;
                                table.TaskExports.Add(db);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                table.TaskExports.Add(db);
                            }
                        }
                        table.SaveChanges();
                        Label1.Text = "Data has been Exported";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "cant save this data" + ex;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

All i must to do is inserting loop to iterate this "codes = fields[15]"

```
                List<TaskExport> emList = new List<TaskExport>();
                foreach (var line in Lines)
                {
                    Fields = line.Split(new char[] { ';' });

                            emList.Add(

                                new TaskExport
                                {
                                    Plant = Fields[0],
                                    Prod__Number = Fields[1],
                                    Order_Number = Fields[2],
                                    Vehicle_Number = Fields[3],
                                    Delivery_Number = Fields[4],
                                    Vehicle_Type = Fields[5],
                                    Engine_Type = Fields[6],
                                    Plant_Dispatch_Date = Fields[7],
                                    Interior = Fields[8],
                                    Paint = Fields[9],
                                    Model = Fields[10],
                                    Country_Name = Fields[11],
                                    Engine_Number = Fields[12],
                                    Sample_Digit = Fields[13],
                                    Number_Of_Code = Fields[14],
                                    Codes = Fields[15],
                                    Number_Of_FZEG = Fields[215],
                                    Country_Code = Fields[216]
                                });
```

I have to loop that "codes" field until the fields[15] reach to fields[214]..
somebody please help me with this problem -_-???

Comment: You have large amount of code. Just tell us what you want to do and where did you stuck in generalized way.

Comment: What you mean a loop? Or you mean you want to create a loop to fill `field[16]` ~ `field[213]`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you need to get all attributes of class in order they are declared.

I hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23919370/3664659)  will help you to do so.

Then loop over your property list (assume it's in `props` variable) and set values.

```
                    List<TaskExport> emList = new List<TaskExport>();
                    foreach (var line in Lines)
                    {
                        Fields = line.Split(new char[] { ';' });
                        TaskExport taskExport = new TaskExport();
                        for(int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
                        {
                            prop[i].SetValue(taskExport, Convert.ChangeType(Fields[i], propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
                        }
                        emList.Add(taskExport);
                   }
```

Comment: @stucker1998 Are you getting any error there. Name should give propertyname as string.

Comment: the way write the syntax is same as my menthor.. but i dont really understand what is .Name  ?? yes, i've got error there, please explain to me im in deadline

Comment: i still dont get it ? -_- can you show me how should i create that .Name ?

Comment: I haven't used Name in recent update? What's the issue now?

Comment: you havent show me actually.. still error, if i type point symbol there, it will show the list.. such as ToString() and GetType again.. i dont really know what .Name it is, and at this point im to afraid to ask to my menthor