# Call a class function from an explicit interface function with the same name

Tags: c#, interface, explicit-interface

The attached code works as expected, it prints 'Something!',
but is it **defined** behaviour (to call the 'normal' method from the 'explicit' method)?

I have searched for various combinations of 'explicit interface call method/function', but all I could find were examples about the difference between implicit and explicitly defined interface functions, and how to call an explicitly defined function.

```
interface ISomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}
class Something : ISomething
{
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something!");
    }

    void ISomething.DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        ISomething thing = new Something();
        thing.DoSomething();
    }
};
```

Comment: explicit interface is only visible if derived class is casted to this interface ... implicit works like  public method so you can calll it having either reference to interface type or class type ... and yes, it is defined behviour

Comment: [an example with public method and explicit interface](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nXrO12) ... when you have reference to the class it calls class method ... if you have reference to the underlaying interface it calls interface memthod ... while instance is the same

Comment: "but is it defined behaviour?" - **yes** - [despite some exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1860615/159145) C# doesn't really have the same UB cop-outs that C and C++ has - and your posted program's behaviour is _fully_ defined w.r.t. the published CLR/CLI and C# specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will have the same output no matter how things work. I suggest using next for clearer understanding:

```cs
class Something : ISomething
{
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something!");
    }

    void ISomething.DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Explicit Something!");
    }
};
```

Which will print `Explicit Something!` for your `Main`. As for why for both implementations - as draft C# 7.0 specification [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces#1762-explicit-interface-member-implementations):

> **It is not possible to access an explicit interface member implementation through its qualified interface member name in a method invocation, property access, event access, or indexer access**. **An explicit interface member implementation can only be accessed through an interface instance**, and is in that case referenced simply by its member name.

So `DoSomething()` call in original `ISomething.DoSomething()` implementation is call to the `Something.DoSomething()` and not to `ISomething.DoSomething()`. `ISomething.DoSomething()` is no accessible cause it requires an interface instance. If you rename `ISomething.DoSomething` to for example `ISomething.DoSomething1` you will see that it is not accessible inside `ISomething.DoSomething1` call unless you cast `this` to interface:

```
interface ISomething
{
    void DoSomething1();
}

class Something : ISomething
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something!");
    }

    void ISomething.DoSomething1()
    {
        // DoSomething1(); // The name 'DoSomething1' does not exist in the current context
        // ((ISomething)this).DoSomething1(); // will obviously end in SO
        Console.WriteLine("ISomething.DoSomething1!");
    }
}
```

Also can be useful [interface mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces#1765-interface-mapping) section:

> Notable implications of the interface-mapping algorithm are:
>
> - Explicit interface member implementations take precedence over other members in the same class or struct when determining the class or struct member that implements an interface member.
> - Neither non-public nor static members participate in interface mapping.

Comment: I know how your example works, but that does not answer my question: Is it defined behaviour if I call the 'normal' function from the 'explicit' function.

Comment: @MarkJansen yes it is. see the quote in bold.